# CMD batch hangs on evaluating %~ parameters with UNC paths

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

When accessing a script file hosted from a W2k12 Server from another W2012 Server, CMD hangs when %~ parameters are being evaluated. OTOH on W2008 servers executing the same file CMD does not hang there. All servers accessing the file over the network get the same GPO, and the same domain admin account is being used accessing the script file.

Here is my test environment:

- ServerA (W2012 R2) hosts **testcase.cmd** on **\\ServerA\share\path**
- ServerB (W2008 R2) accesses the above script file
- ServerC (W2012 R2) accesses the above script file

Here is a test script, being started by double click via Explorer:

```
@ECHO OFF
 SETLOCAL
 ECHO Testcase is starting
 ECHO This Script is called %~nx0 and 
 ECHO it resides in the directory %~dp0
 PAUSE
```

Output on either Server B or Server C, accessing the script file via **Z:\path**

```
Testcase is starting
This Script is called testcase.cmd and
it resides in the directory Z:\path\
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Output on Server B, accessing the script file via **\\ServerA\share\path**

```
'\\ServerA\share\path'
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
Testcase is starting
This Script is called testcase.cmd and
it resides in the directory \\ServerA\share\path
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Output on Server C, accessing the script file via **\\ServerA\share\path**

```
'\\ServerA\share\path'
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
Testcase is starting
```

** HERE IT HANGS! **

The same occurs on evaluating %~ parameters in a FOR loop in a CMD script:

```
FOR %%a IN (\\ServerA\share\path\*.cmd) DO ECHO %%~nxa
```

As well with only %a when executed manually in a DOS window.

Has anyone seen this before, and possibly found a solution?
Thanks in advance!